# Error While Flashing The Minix Neo X8-H Plus

Tags: adb, 4.4-kitkat, rom-flashing, fastboot, boot-loop

I have tried everything I can think of, know about / usually would do in a situation like this. I have watched multiple tutorials, [guides](https://theminixforum.com/index.php?threads/neo-x8-h-plus-lollipop-os-fw-20170612.45/#post-71) and more. I went to the official [website itself](https://theminixforum.com) multiple times to see if I missed anything, but to no avail nothing works. One day the box just stopped working, so then, I looked up the fix and they say that I am supposed to re-flash the box. I did that, and while I was doing that, this error popped up. I have tried multiple things including:

- Using a different cable other than the one that came in the box ( data cable )
- Using a different computer
- Using a different port
- Using a different wall socket

etc.

It has been over ***4 years*** now since this box has stopped working, and it has been sitting around my house ever since collecting dust and it is about time that this gets fixed, thrown away in the trash, or scrapped for parts.

The smart box is a [Minix Neo X8-H Plus](http://www.minix.us/products/NEO-X8-H-plus.html) that ran **Android 4.4 Kitkat** and uses an **ARM Cortex-A9 Quad Core** processor with **2 GB of DDR3**. It used to run very smoothly until that one day. I hope someone can assist me here to hopefully getting this fixed. Thank you all in advance for any help or support that you can provide me with.

The error described above is displayed below. It always seems to occur **right** after the stage `formatting` before getting stuck at that stage for an extended period of time, at **3% Completion** before going onto **4% Completion** and then spitting out this error:

[image: Error While Flashing Box: [0x30201006]UBOOT/Disk Initialize/Send Command/Time Out]

The newer versions of this [**Amlogic USB Burning Tool**](https://androidmtk.com/download-amlogic-usb-burning-tool) usually crash at this stage after displaying a different error entitled **"Failed to Parse Image File"**, no matter which image file I use.